# How can I display my element dynamically based on data's fields?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, user-interface, frontend

I have my data in below:

```
  fakeData = [
        {
            "option_name" : 'optionA',
            "display_line_num" : 1
      },
        {
            "option_name" : 'optionB',
            "display_line_num" : 2
      },
        {
            "option_name" : 'optionC',
            "display_line_num" : 2
      },
        {
            "option_name" : 'optionD',
            "display_line_num" : 3
      },
        {
            "option_name" : 'optionE',
            "display_line_num" : 4
      },
        {
            "option_name" : 'optionF',
            "display_line_num" : 4
      }
    ];
```

and I am trying to make my html look like [desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lrsl.png)

The display_line_num represent which row the element should be placed.
I am pretty lost on how to approach to this.

[my try here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/try-to-display-items-based-on-line-num?file=src/main.ts)
I tried to create a hashmap where key is the line number, and value is how many options are in that line number. However, I am still lost.
I am stuck for a long time, and I wonder what are some good ways to approach this?

I know that we may need to use *ngFor, for example , <li *ngFor="let item of items;"> ....

but there will be a nested for loop which one row can have several options, and sometimes a row only has a option. How can I handle these circumstances?

Can someone give me a hint?
Thank you!

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects, it might have something that can help your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your `mapDatas` function:

```
mapDatas( data: any ){

  const dataObj:any = {}

  this.fakeData.forEach(data => {
    const {display_line_num: key, option_name: value} = data;
    dataObj[key] = dataObj[key] ? [...dataObj[key], value] : [value]
  });

  return Object.values(dataObj);

}
```

Here we are iterating through the `fakeData` array and pushing each item's `option_name` value in a nested array and the index of each array is the `display_line_num` of each item. So, when more than one element have the same `display_line_num`, they will be put in the same array.
And finally, we are returning the object converted to an array. Now you can iterate through each item using `ngFor` in your template.